# Add a file to project resources using C#

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I'm creating SpecFlow tests for an application that uses an xml settings file (example, C:\ssis\mySettingsFile.xml) to run.  In one test, I want to save the file to disk, and then add that file to my project resources and clean up the disk location.  Then, another test will unpack the resource to a temporary directory and use it from there.

I'm clear about the unpacking part, but is there a way to programatically pack the file into a project resource rather than manually adding it to the project using the VS GUI and marking it as an embedded resource?

I know this is wrong, but I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
string myPath = "C:\ssis\mySettingsFile.xml";
TestHelper.ResourceDirectory = "$\...\...\Project.Folder.Resources";
myResource = TestHelper.PackResource(myPath);
myResource.IsEmbeddedResource = true;
```

...where PackResource method saves the file to the project resources.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a Resource Folder and add your xml to it.
When you click on Properties of the project, there will be a Resources tab wherein you can see  your file.
To access the file, you can use ProjectNamespace.Properties.Resources.yourfilename.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to specifically add it using C# in my test class because it doesn't exist in any state I want to save until after the test has run.  I'll try to add an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I found [this forum post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926378/how-do-i-replace-embedded-resources-in-a-net-assembly-programmatically) that seems to do what I am looking to do.  However upon further research, it would probably be counter intuitive to the result I want/need.  Since saving a file into my resources would change the state of the test each time it's run, it essentially invalidates the test.  

To keep a sterile test environment, I'll delete any temporary files that I unpack, and manually embed my files for the tests that require them as suggested above.  Thanks!